# How to open local HTML from a Thunderbird add-on preference pane?

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

My Thunderbird add-on contains a help.html file, which can be opened from the preferences pane. This is the code:

```
  <label value="Open help window" 
 onclick="window.open('chrome://foo/locale/help.html', 'Help', 'chrome');" 
 class="text-link"/>
```

Under Windows, the HTML is displayed fine, but under MacOS, the background is transparent.
Also, the link only opens once.

How do I properly open a local text from a Thunderbird preference pane? My add-has no other window (it is a contextual menu).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the `openURL` function on the global window?

Comment: I just tried window.openURL, but no windows opens, no message on the error console.